# SQL-sales sum over past N week including week with 0 sales

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I want to display sum  of 4 weeks sales every week(current week plus the previous 3 week) per item.

**Raw data**

```
+--------+--------+----------+
| Item   | Week   | sales    |
+--------+--------+----------+
|   a    |      1 |     10   |
|   a    |      2 |     10   |
|   a    |      4 |     10   |
|   a    |      7 |     10   |
|   a    |      8 |     10   |
|   a    |     10 |     10   |
|   b    |      1 |     10   |
|   b    |      2 |     10   |
|   b    |      4 |     10   |
|   b    |      7 |     10   |
|   b    |      8 |     10   |
|   b    |     10 |     10   |
+--------+--------+----------+
```

**Expected Result(take item a as example)**

```
+------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Item | Week |                        sales                         |
+------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
| a    |    1 | 10                                                   |
| a    |    2 | 20                                                   |
| a    |    3 | 30                                                   |
| a    |    4 | 30                                                   |
| a    |    5 | 20(Note: sales of Week 5+Week 4+Week 3+Week 2)       |
| a    |    6 | 10                                                   |
| a    |    7 | 20[Note: 10(Week 7)+0(Week 6)+0(Week 5)+10 (Week 4)] |
| a    |    8 | 20                                                   |
| a    |    9 | 20                                                   |
| a    |   10 | 30(Note: sales of Week 10+Week 9+Week 8+Week 7)      |
+------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried to use

```sql
sum (sales) over (partition by item order by week row 3 preceding)
```

However, it skips the Week with no sale record and add up all the none-zero values. For example: For Week 7, sum over calculates result as 40 as it adds the sales from Week 7,4,2,1.
Is there a way to achieve the expected results?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am using redshift.

Answer (score 0):

For every week, if your table is table

```
SELECT sum(B.sales), A.week as curweek As totalsales
FROM table A, table B
WHERE curweek - B.week <4 
AND curweek - B.week >=0
GROUP BY curweek
```

Comment: it will work if I only need to calculate the number for the current week. However, I need to calculate the result for every week. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT week,Item ,sum(sales) WHERE (curweek - week < 4) group by week,Item
```

Comment: Can you offer some explanation of your approach?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26176288)

Answer (score 0):

**As the question did not mention RDBMS, I tested below code in SQL Server. The below solution is for SQL Server**

I am doing below activities:

1. Generate all combination of week, Item
2. For the combination, generate sum(sales) for preceding 4 weeks
3. Remove the weeks, which are not present in the original list

```sql
DECLARE @table TABLE (Item CHAR(1), Week TINYINT, sales INT)

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES ('a', 1, 10), ('a', 2, 10), ('a', 4, 10), ('a', 7, 10), ('a', 8, 10), ('a', 10, 10), ('b', 1, 10), ('b', 2, 10), ('b', 4, 10), ('b', 7, 10), ('b', 8, 10), ('b', 10, 10);;

WITH CTE_ItemWeek
AS (
    SELECT Item, Week
    FROM (
        VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)
        ) AS t(week)
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT Item
        FROM @table
        ) A
    )
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t1.Item, CASE 
            WHEN t2.Week IS NULL
                THEN LAG(t2.week) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY t1.Item ORDER BY t2.week
                        )
            ELSE t2.week
            END AS week, SUM(t2.sales) OVER (
            PARTITION BY t1.Item ORDER BY t1.week ROWS BETWEEN 3 preceding
                    AND CURRENT ROW
            ) AS total_sales
    FROM CTE_ItemWeek AS t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @table AS t2 ON t1.Item = t2.Item
        AND t1.week = t2.week
    ) AS t
WHERE week IS NOT NULL
```

**Result Set**

```
+------+------+-------------+
| Item | week | total_sales |
+------+------+-------------+
| a    |    1 |          10 |
| a    |    2 |          20 |
| a    |    4 |          30 |
| a    |    7 |          20 |
| a    |    8 |          20 |
| a    |   10 |          30 |
| b    |    1 |          10 |
| b    |    2 |          20 |
| b    |    4 |          30 |
| b    |    7 |          20 |
| b    |    8 |          20 |
| b    |   10 |          30 |
+------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Sorry. I should have checked it. I missed and directly went for solution. my bad. will take care in future.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, agreed. updated my answer with RDBMS information.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to see the sum for the existing weeks (so not filling the missing ones), this can be achieved in standard SQL by using a range, rather than rows:

```
select item, 
       week,
       sum (sales) over (partition by item order by week range between 3 preceding and current row)
from the_table
order by item, week;
```

If you need to fill in the missing weeks as rows, the answer depends heavily on the DBMS being used. In Postgres you can do the following:

```
with items as (
  select distinct item
  from data
), all_weeks as (
  select i.item, g.week
  from items i
    cross join generate_series(1,10) as g(week)
)    
select t.item,
       t.week,
       sum (d.sales) over (partition by t.item order by t.week range between 3 preceding and current row)
from all_weeks t
  left join data d on d.item = t.item and d.week = t.week
```

For other DBMS systems, the `generate_series()` call can be replaced with a fixed number of weeks:

```
select i.item, g.week
from items i
  cross join ( values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10) ) as g(week)
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=717186d8b4d895420bad66befe6dc83b)